# pass a variable over regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a regex

```
  \d{2}.*?word
```

I need to change this for

```
  \d{i}.*?word
```

and increment "i"

```
i++

var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));
var newText = regex.Replace("textstring43288482383483833638.....word", "\d{i}.*?word", 1); 
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));
var newText = regex.Replace("textstring43288482383483833638.....word", "\d{2}.*?word", 1); 

var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));
var newText = regex.Replace("textstring43288482383483833638.....word", "\d{3}.*?word", 1);
```

and stop to the last match.

please help me with this

Comment: Could you please post your code, seems like its just about use a String.Format() for me (or I haven't understood your question).

Comment: I plan to use index
I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Why not just do `(\d+)` and then measure the size of the matched group?

Comment: the problem is that he planned to do to implement a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you perhaps use [String interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)? Should work by prefixing the string that contains the regex with a `$`.

```
regex.Replace("textstring43288482383483833638.....word", $"\d{i}.*?word", 1);
```

Seems to me like that should work if `i` is already in the current scope.

Comment: very   thank  you .